# How to iterate over the class in python? (yfinance class)

Tags: python, for-loop, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I'm trying to get some data for multiple stocks, but simple `for loop` does not iterate over the class.
For example:

```
    In[2]:  import yfinance as yf
            stock = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
            stock.info.get('sharesOutstanding')
    Out[2]: 4375479808
```

And when I'm trying something like:

```
t = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
for str in t:
    stock = yf.Ticker(str)
    a = []
    a = stock.info.get('sharesOutstanding')
```

I get only MSFT shares outstanding.
Ideally, the result must be a dataframe like:

```
     sharesOutstanding
AAPl 4375479808
MSFT 7606049792
```

Any ideas how to realise it? Actually I have list of about 6375 stocks, but if there would be a solve for two stocks, then code cample can be used for multiple stocks, I think.

**PROBLEM SOLVING:**

```
a = []
b = []
for str in t:
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(str)
        a.append(stock.info.get('sharesOutstanding'))
        b.append(stock.info.get('symbol'))
    except KeyError:
        continue
    except IndexError:
        continue
shares_ots = pd.DataFrame(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely occurs because the `a` list is declared locally within the loop, meaning that the data it holds is overridden each iteration.

To solve the issue, we can declare the list outside of the scope of the loop. This way, it can retain its information.

```py
t = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
a = []
for str in t:
    stock = yf.Ticker(str)
    a.append(stock.info.get('sharesOutstanding'))
```

Alternatively, you can use another built-in function in the API as shown in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/).

```py
tickers = yf.Tickers('aapl msft')
# ^ returns a named tuple of Ticker objects

# access each ticker
tickers.msft.info.get('sharesOutstanding'))
tickers.aapl.info.get('sharesOutstanding'))
```

---

**EDIT**

If you prefer, you can simplify the loop with list comprehension as shown:

```py
t = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
a = [yf.Ticker(str).info.get('sharesOutstanding') for str in t]
```

Because the `Ticker(str).info` object is a Python dictionary, we can pass in an additional argument to the `get` function to specify a default fallback value.

```
a = [yf.Ticker(str).info.get('sharesOutstanding', 'NaN') for str in t]
```

In this case, if the dictionary does not have the `'sharesOutstanding'` key, it will default to `None`. This way, we can ensure that `len(a) == len(t)`.

To create a pandas data frame, try something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(a, t, columns=['sharesOutstanding'])
```

Comment: Great! First way is good and more suitable for my problem, because I have list of 6375 stocks.  But how I can automatically create a df which would contain a ticker corresponding to ticker's `sharesOutstanding` value?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what format you want your DataFrame to be in, but how about something like `df = pd.DataFrame(a, t, columns=['sharesOutstanding']) `?

Comment: I need a DataFrame due to the fact that some tickers doesnt have a `sharesOutstaning`. In this case, `a` and `t` will not match each other by length so I can't just add them to DataFrame, because `sharesOutstanding` value will not match the exact company. So I need something like `stock.info.get('symbol')` within the loop and then collect `symbol` and `sharesOutstanding` as a row in DataFrame.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. But I don't think that should be a problem since the `get` method will return `None` if a ticker doesn't have `'sharesOutstanding'`. You can also change the default fallback value `None` to something like `'NaN'` as I have shown in the edit. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm get `key[0]['yearly'] = cleanup(data[item][key[2]]) KeyError: 'cashflowStatements'`. Seems like some tickers doesnt have a published statements in yahoo finance. And then I'm use `except KeyError: continue`, so that's why I need also `stock.info.get('symbol')` to know what exact tickers are have a `sharesOutstaning`.P.S. Also occurs `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` after I used `except KeyError`, but I will search solving this problem after I would be able to collect  both `symbol` and `sharesOutstanding` values.

Comment: Before I try to write down code, a question: how is `t` going to differ from the list you get by running queries on `get('symbol')`?

Comment: I have found a solution modifying your code! Many thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating an array on each iteration, and not correctly appending to that array anyway. Try this:

```
t = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
a = []
for str in t:
    stock = yf.Ticker(str)
    a.append(stock.info.get('sharesOutstanding'))
```